# Bitcoin rpc testnet balance and transaction not visible

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, json-rpc, testnet, balance

I'm using bitcoind-0.15.0.1 version & My Wallet Address is: [muweVvHKnK1bE88pUsrpSAPuWry1V1AmHZ](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/address/muweVvHKnK1bE88pUsrpSAPuWry1V1AmHZ/)

But whenever checking balance with following command:

`bitcoin-cli getreceivedbyaddress 'muweVvHKnK1bE88pUsrpSAPuWry1V1AmHZ'`

It appears to be 0.00000000, while the wallet has 0.0007 BTC stored!

*Bitcoin.conf* indicates I'm connected to the testnet: `testnet = 1`

What is the problem?

Comment: Is muweVvHKnK1bE88pUsrpSAPuWry1V1AmHZ an address of the wallet you're querying? What does `getbalance` say?

Comment: My wallet address = muweVvHKnK1bE88pUsrpSAPuWry1V1AmHZ

bitcoin-cli getbalance = 0.00000000

There is a balance in the wallet but it does not appear.

Comment: Then I think you're querying the wrong wallet. You can't ask for information about addresses that are not in that wallet itself.

Comment: wallet true. registered in node. but no balance appears.

Comment: How did you inport the address? What does "getaddressinfo muweVvHKnK1bE88pUsrpSAPuWry1V1AmHZ" say?

Comment: getaddressinfo Method not found. because i use node version 0.15.0.1

Comment: Then you should update urgently! You can use `validateaddress` instead of `getaddressinfo` in 0.15.

Comment: ./bitcoin-cli validateaddress "muweVvHKnK1bE88pUsrpSAPuWry1V1AmHZ"
{
  "isvalid": true,
  "address": "muweVvHKnK1bE88pUsrpSAPuWry1V1AmHZ",
  "scriptPubKey": "76a9149e3d4e1e102c388f26f2e4d6cabe38d7be0187ea88ac",
  "ismine": true,
  "iswatchonly": false,
  "isscript": false,
  "pubkey": "031365b3a9d073ac31fc2a92ddf3c894972a5e0323b764e963fc2d8e229dc44569",
  "iscompressed": true,
  "account": "testnet-icin",
  "timestamp": 1567514729,
  "hdkeypath": "m/0'/0'/8'",
  "hdmasterkeyid": "ab73360cdaf8a69a63ed1c816129c4d9a33d4c1c"
}

Comment: Are you fully synchronized with the chain? What does getblockchaininfo say?

Comment: {
  "chain": "test",
  "blocks": 1012566,
  "headers": 1576881,
  "bestblockhash": "000000000000019bb5aa7db72fd5c4c01e42b80815a0e80d9ee2dce46aaf548d",
  "difficulty": 3241932.284902167,
  "mediantime": 1477459028,
  "verificationprogress": 0.4805068858447337,
  "chainwork": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018c885775e04566600",
  "pruned": false,
  "softforks": [
    {
      "id": "bip34",
      "version": 2,
      "reject": {
        "status": true
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip66",
      "version": 3,
      "reject": {

Comment: "status": true
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip65",
      "version": 4,
      "reject": {
        "status": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "bip9_softforks": {
    "csv": {
      "status": "active",
      "startTime": 1456790400,
      "timeout": 1493596800,
      "since": 770112
    },
    "segwit": {
      "status": "active",
      "startTime": 1462060800,
      "timeout": 1493596800,
      "since": 834624
    }
  }
}

Comment: Ok, you're half a million blocks behind. Just wait until it fully synchronizes.

Comment: how long does it take? I encode a payment system with bitcoin. what should I do to not wait so long?

Comment: Depending on your hardware and settings a few hours to a few days. There are many questions about speeding things up.

Comment: I am using ubuntu virtualbox. I think this is the reason for the delay.i will buy vps server. What features do you recommend?

Comment: RAM, fast disk, and set the dbcache option in your config file appropriately.